# after install hive and run hive , occured several problem and can't hive run

Tags: mysql, hive, mariadb

Installed versions:

- hadoop: hadoop-2.7.7
- mariadb: mariadb-10.1.44-linux-x86_64
- hive: 2.3.6

Log:

```
[root@master ~]# hive
20/01/30 17:14:13 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.metastore.local does not exist

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/opt/apps/hive/lib/hive-common-1.2.2.jar!/hive-log4j.properties

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:141)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Error(s) were found while auto-creating/validating the datastore for classes. The errors are printed in the log, and are attached to this exception.
NestedThrowables:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=103) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INITIALLY DEFERRED' at line 1
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.**getJDOExceptionForNucleusException**(NucleusJDOHelper.java:451)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:732)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:752)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.createDatabase(ObjectStore.java:521)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.createDatabase(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB_core(HiveMetaStore.java:604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:624)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5768)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(**SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)**
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=103) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INITIALLY DEFERRED' at line 1
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:238)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:171)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:243)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:332)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.execute(MariaDbStatement.java:383)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.StatementHandle.execute(StatementHandle.java:254)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.AbstractTable.executeDdlStatement(AbstractTable.java:760)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.TableImpl.createForeignKeys(TableImpl.java:527)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.TableImpl.createConstraints(TableImpl.java:429)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.performTablesValidation(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3459)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.addClassTablesAndValidate(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3190)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.run(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2841)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.AbstractSchemaTransaction.execute(AbstractSchemaTransaction.java:122)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.addClasses(RDBMSStoreManager.java:1605)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.addClass(AbstractStoreManager.java:954)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getDatastoreClass(RDBMSStoreManager.java:679)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getPropertiesForGenerator(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2045)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.getStrategyValue(AbstractStoreManager.java:1365)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.newObjectId(ExecutionContextImpl.java:3827)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.setIdentity(JDOStateManager.java:2571)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.initialiseForPersistentNew(JDOStateManager.java:513)
    at org.datanucleus.state.ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.newForPersistentNew(ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.java:232)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.newObjectProviderForPersistentNew(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1414)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectInternal(ExecutionContextImpl.java:2218)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectWork(ExecutionContextImpl.java:2065)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1913)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextThreadedImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextThreadedImpl.java:217)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:727)
    ... 35 more

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your **MariaDB server version for the right** syntax to use near 'INITIALLY DEFERRED' at line 1
Query is: ALTER TABLE DATABASE_PARAMS ADD CONSTRAINT DATABASE_PARAMS_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (DB_ID) REFERENCES DBS (DB_ID) INITIALLY DEFERRED 
java thread: main
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.LogQueryTool.exceptionWithQuery(LogQueryTool.java:121)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:233)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:326)
    ... 59 more
```

Comment: Please tell us what exactly your question is, and what you've tried doing so far

Comment: it's solved. create  metastore  database to mysql  1) step create database metastore;
flush privileges;

grant all privileges on metastore.* to 'hive'@'localhost' identified by 'password' ;

flush privileges; 
use metastore;

source /hive home directory/ /scripts/metastore/upgrade/mysql/hive-schema-2.3.0.mysql.sql
commit;                2)step   set database name  in  hive-site.xml      <property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL </name>
<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
<description> jdbc metastore  </description>
</property>

Comment: Please post this comment as an answer to your question and mark it as the accepted answer. Comments with code fragments are pretty unreadable